# cpanel spam general expression filter for body contains a string of letters and numbers with no spaces

Tags: regex, cpanel, spam-prevention

I am having some problems with some spam email. The only common thread for all of these emails is that they have a link with a long url with more than 40 numbers and letters without a space or any other strange characters.

Using CPanel I am trying to setup a filter for this spam. One option is "body -> contains", but I don't think it works with general expressions.

Then there is the option "body -> matches regex". I assume that I would use the expression /[0-9a-zA-Z]{40,}/ to match the string, but this does not just see if that string is "contained" somewhere in the body. It tries to match it. Correct?

/[0-9a-zA-Z]{40,}/

How do I write a general expression mail filter using cpanel to just see if the long string is somewhere in the body?

=================================

This is what ended up working for me:

This is what ended up working:

([a-zA-Z0-9_]{40})

Comment: Nope, it will both match it and search if the string is contained somewhere in the body: here, that's the same thing. If you were using `^[...]{40,}$` that would be a different story, but as you're not... The match will only be the 40+ string of characters, but since you just want to see if there is a match at all you can assume returning anything means spam mail.

Comment: This is what ended up working:

([a-zA-Z0-9_]{40})